# Python Pandas - Fillna(method=ffill) results in NameError

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe and then used a pivot_table to transpose the data from rows to columns.

```
In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('Transform.csv') 
In [7]: pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index="Structure", columns='Type') 
ranges = pivot.filter(items=['Min','Mid','Max']) 
print(ranges)

Type        Min Mid Max  
Structure 
AE_BA10     456 543 756  
AE_BA12     0   0   0  
AE_BA14     0   0   0  
AE_BA16     0   0   0
```

After I make updates to the values I would like to change the data from columns to rows so I stacked the data back.

```
In [6]: ranges.stack() 
Out[6]: Structure Type 
        AE_BA10   Min 456 
                  Mid 543 
                  Max 756 
        AE_BA12   Min 0 
                  Mid 0 
                  Max 0 
        AE_BA14   Min 0 
                  Mid 0 
                  Max 0 
        AE_BA16   Min 0 
                  Mid 0 
                  Max 0
```

I'm trying to get the data to in the column "Structure" to repeat the row labels so it look like this:

```
Structure   Type    
AE_BA10     Min   456
AE_BA10     Mid   543
AE_BA10     Max   756
AE_BA12     Min   0
AE_BA12     Mid   0
AE_BA12     Max   0
AE_BA14     Min   0
AE_BA14     Mid   0
AE_BA14     Max   0
AE_BA16     Min   0
AE_BA16     Mid   0
AE_BA16     Max   0
```

I tried using the fillna(method=ffill) but I get a NameError with it.

```
In [8]: ranges.fillna(method=ffill)

NameError Traceback (most recent call last) in () ----> 1 ranges.fillna(method=ffill)

NameError: name 'ffill' is not defined
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing incorrectly?

EDIT: I put ffill in quotes but it still doesn't populate the structure all the way down.

```
In [19]: stacked.fillna(method='ffill')
Out[19]:
Structure  Type
AE_BA10    Min      456
           Mid      543
           Max      756
AE_BA12    Min        0
           Mid        0
           Max        0
AE_BA14    Min        0
           Mid        0
           Max        0
AE_BA16    Min        0
           Mid        0
           Max        0
dtype: float64
```

Final Edit: Ako's solution worked.

```
In [37]: ranges.stack().reset_index(level=0)

      Structure   0
Type        
Min   AE_BA10     456
Mid   AE_BA10     543
Max   AE_BA10     756
Min   AE_BA12     0
Mid   AE_BA12     0
Max   AE_BA12     0
```

Comment: you need to put ffill in quotes--you pass it as a name so python thinks it is a reference to an object.

Comment: Thanks, I tried putting it in quotes but it still doesn't fill "Structure" all the way down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NameError is a good indication--you need to put `ffill` in quotes--you pass it as a name so python thinks it is a reference to an object.

(You may also want to look at the `pd.melt()` method for restructuring your data.)

**Edit 1:**

In addition to the `NameError`, you encounter zeroes. Try unstacking your data so max is a column rather than a part of a `MultiIndex`, and use `ffill` on that frame.

I don't have your data, but something like:

```
stacked.stack(level=1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Should do the trick.

**Edit 2:**

OP was really asking about getting the index to repeat for all rows which is not an `fillna()` issue. To get at that, this will do:

```
ranges.stack().reset_index(level=0)
```

Comment: Actually it looks like your `ranges` dataframe from earlier has that structure. Try `ranges.fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @ako, but it still isn't working. ranges.fillna(method='ffill') brings it back to the original. stacked.stack(level1).fillna(method='ffill') gives me an attribute error. I will look into pd.melt().

Comment: OK. Try to provide data for a reproducible [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I found a missing `=` in my code. Note instead `stacked.stack(level=1).fillna(method='ffill')`

Comment: Oh. The other thing I noticed is the `fillna` won't help because you don't have missing values. You have 0's. My answer assumed missing values.

Comment: Is there a way to fill in the "Structure" so that the label is "filled out" for every row? I'm wondering if fillna isn't the correct solution.

Comment: Another "aah". You are talking about the index--I read it as you wanted to fill the the actual numeric value. In that case, just try `ranges.stack().reset_index(level=0)`.